# How do I format this multiplication table as shown?

Tags: python

Here is my code thus far:

```
    n = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: "))
    if n > 10:
        n = int(input("Please enter a smaller number (must not be greater than 10): "))

    for k in range(1, n+1):
        print(k, end=" ")
        print('-' * 10, end=" ")
    print()

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(i, end=" ")
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            print(i * j, end=" ")
        print()
```

Assuming the user inputs 4 as n, I need to display a multiplication table that looks like the following:

```
1 2 3 4
----------
1 | 1 2 3 4
2 | 2 4 6 8
3 | 3 6 9 12
4 | 4 8 12 16
```

The current header looks like this:

```
1 ----------- 2 ---------- 3 ----------- 4 ----------
```

What am I missing? The dashes should be on their own line. I have tried inserting the lines for the header including dashes in various places, including inside the i and j loops.

Comment: What error are you getting or what is your output currently?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring the line `print('-' * 10, end=" ")` outside of the for loop since you don't want the script to print out that header line once instead of n times. Other than that you just need to add a bar after the row index to get the downward border line.

```
n = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: "))
if n > 10:
    n = int(input("Please enter a smaller number (must not be greater than 10): "))

for k in range(1, n+1):
    print(k, end=" ")

print()
print('-' * 10)

for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(i, "|", end=" ")
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        print(i * j, end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
n = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: "))
if n > 10:
    n = int(input("Please enter a smaller number (must not be greater than 10): "))

for k in range(1, n+1):
    print(k, end=" ")
    # print('-' * 10, end=" ")
print()
print("----------")

for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(i, end=" | ")
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        print(i * j, end=" ")
    print()
```

output

```
Please enter a number between 1 and 10: 4
1 2 3 4
----------
1 | 1 2 3 4
2 | 2 4 6 8
3 | 3 6 9 12
4 | 4 8 12 16
```